# GAE BlobstoreUploadHandler doesn't recognize files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, blobstore

When I send a request from a client like this:

```
with open(config.datafile, "rb") as f:
  r = requests.post(config.endpoint, files={"file": f})
  print r.text
```

to my GAE app like this:

```
class FileUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):

  def post(self):
    self.response.out.write(self.get_uploads())
```

I would expect to get something like this:

```
{
  "file": "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\nline 7\nline 8\nline 9\n"
},
```

but instead the request is putting the file data in data so that if I change the app to look like this:

```
class FileUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):

  def post(self):
    self.response.out.write(self.request.get("file"))
```

I now get a response body like:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
```

This seems contrary to the documentation. Can someone explain why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are sending the file to the URL mapped to FileUploadHandler. This is not the right thing to do.

You need to upload the file to the url returned from blobstore.create_upload_url.

Even then you cannot access the file through the request. You have to use a BlobReader to access it.

Here are the relevant docs:

Upload to blobstore: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob

Read from blobstore: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass

Comment: Now I see. Thanks for the help, I now have working code after redirecting to  a uploadhandler with "return redirect(blobstore.create_upload_url("/api/upload"), code=307)"